# Mobile battery of one mobile for another

Tags: mobile, battery, mobile-devices

Can i connect mobile battery of one smart phone for another. I'll use all 3 pin connections. Is there any risk involved?
I'm facing some problem with my mobile battery and phone switches off all of a sudden. I'm using huawei ascend P1.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ther is no problem replacing bettery from one phone to another as far aws voltage and size of the bettery is same. mobile switching off suddencly can of many reason bettery replacement is the one solution from them other could be your mobile is not storing charge properly and charging ic got problem as far as HUAWEI Ascend P1 concern it store bettery via its main flash ic so their is not charging IC with it.

Regards
Imran Qasim

Comment: Thank you Qasim. To add further, i have checked the battery status and health condition in mobile( code *#*#4636#*#*) and it shows scale 100% and Battery health as good. How can i further test and find the root cause?

Comment: there are different tools to check the basic functionality of a mobile specially the MultiMeter and DC Powersupply , other thant that you have to take your mobile to a shop for services may be it have some sort of shortage insidel, which make the bettery drained or feel like its drained